# mysql query to get all reviews for every company

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with tables like below:

```
Reviews

id | review | companyid

companies

id | name
```

Now i want to get the data back so that i can show each company name with the total number of reviews for the company. Like seen below:

```
company 1 (company name) | 345

company 2 (company name) | 28

company 3 (company name) | 794
```

From here i will make a table using php to display the results

How can i achieve this with MYSQl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` to count the reviews per company and use `JOIN` to get the company name from the other table.

**Query**

```
select t2.name as companyName,coalesce(t1.`count`,0) as `count` from
(
    select companyid,count(companyid) as `count`
    from reviews
    group by companyid
)t1
right join companies t2
on t1.companyid= t2.id;
```

**Sample Output**

**Table - reviews**

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | review | companyid |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |     r1 |         1 |
|  2 |     r2 |         2 |
|  3 |     r3 |         1 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

**Table - companies**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 |   C1 |
|  2 |   C2 |
|  3 |   C3 |
+----+------+
```

**Output**

```
+------+-------+
| name | count |
+------+-------+
|   C1 |     2 |
|   C2 |     1 |
|   C3 |     0 |
+------+-------+
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99e05/4)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
SELECT Count(`r`.`review`) AS `total_reviews`,
       `c`.`company`
FROM   `reviews` AS `r`
       JOIN `companies` AS `c`
            ON `c`.`id` = `r`.`companyid`
```

Comment: total_reviews
name
6976
company 1, i need it to show all the company names with the amount of reviews for each of them

Comment: A GROUP BY clause might be fun

Comment: You definitely needed a `group by`

Comment: removing the inner does the same aswell

Comment: may be multiple companies having same name. so you may need to group by companyid.

Comment: infact 1 more thing, if a company has no reviews it doesnt show on the list, i need it to show as 0

Comment: @MatthewSmart : then you may need to use right join or left join

Comment: @MatthewSmart Please update your question and you'll get an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT r.companyid, c.name, count(r.id) as nb_review
FROM reviews r
INNER JOIN companies c ON (r.companyid = c.id)
GROUP BY r.companyid, c.name;
```

If you also want to see the companies with no reviews, do :

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, count(r.id) as nb_review
FROM companies c
LEFT JOIN reviews r ON (r.companyid = c.id)
GROUP BY c.id, c.name;
```